# Formatting the output of grep

Tags: bash

I'm trying the code below attempting to print "$2" "$5-*")

```
while IFS= read -r a name x x desc; do
   printf '%-15s %s\n' "$name" "$desc"
done < <(grep "^function" ~/.functions)
```

but it seems that the entire line is being assigned to $a

What am I doing wrong? Running grep (GNU grep) 3.7

Thanks

Comment: What are you expecting `IFS=` to do? What separates the fields of your `grep` output?

Comment: separated by spaces

Comment: See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716). Use awk or perl or some other language.  e.g. `awk '/^function/ { printf "%15s", $2; $1=$2=$3=$4=""; $0=$0; print $0 }' ~/.functions`.  or `perl -lane 'if (/^function/) { printf "%15s %s\n", $F[1], join(" ", @F[4..$#F]) }' ~/.functions`

Comment: cas,  Thanks .. I tried awk but couldn't get it to print correctly.  Please post this as the answer.  Thanks again